# AuthenticationManagerBuilder is not present in the spring-security-core, spring-security-web, spring-security-config version 4.2.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-security

I am working on the **Spring boot** and using the latest version `1.5.6.RELEASE` and because of this version I added `spring-boot-starter-security` and it fetches `spring-security-core`, `spring-security-web`, `spring-security-config` version `4.2.3.RELEASE`. But I dont see dependencies present in any of the jar shown in the screen shot

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this because sometimes while downloading the dependency from the central repository into the local repository, dependency gets corrupted and thats causes the issue. In this case, you simply need to delete that dependency and execute the following command again.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```